# Django: Why 'Class' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I built a dictionary list like this

```
lst = [{'name': nameobj, Classobj1: "string", Classobj2: "string"}, \
{'name': nameobj, Classobj1: "string", Classobj2: "string"}]
```

and I'm using

```
for dic in lst:
   for k,v in dic:   # here is the line has probloem! What it happens?
       #process
```

The error message is like "Classname" object is not iterable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating over a dictionary just iterates over the keys, not key-value pairs. So on the line

```
for k,v in dic:
```

Python is taking just a key, such as Classobj1, and trying to unpack it to match it to the tuple k,v. Since Classobj1 can't be iterated over, it can't be unpacked to match two items, which is why you get this error.

To iterate over key-value pairs, use items() or iteritems():

```
for k,v in dic.items():
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dic.iteritems()`.

Comment: Thanks, but what happened to me~

Comment: That is right too. Do you know if there is any differences between our solutions, I mean about speed?Thanks

Comment: I only know rudimentary python. I don't think there is and if there is, it is minimal.

Comment: The difference between keys and iteritems is what's returned. Keys will return an array of keys where iteritems will return an iterator that yields a tuple(key, value). In most cases it's better to use iterators in loops because they do not make a copy of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
for dic in lst:
    for key in dic.keys():
     /* process dic[key] */
```

Comment: It appears from the code posted that he wants the key and the value, .keys() will only return the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dic in lst:
   for k,v in dic.iteritems():   # just added a call to iteritems
       #process
```

You get the '<class obj> is not iterable' error because a `dict` yields its keys when iterating over it, so when you reach say `Classobj1` the program expects `Classobj1` to be an iterable object that will yield values for `k,v`.